# Basemap error: cannot import name 'basemap_data'

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have problems when I want to use Basemap and keep getting this error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'basemap_data' from 'mpl_toolkits' (unknown location)
```

I can tell that Basemap is installed:

```
PS C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Bachelor\Programm> pip show basemap
Name: basemap
Version: 1.3.3
Summary: Plot data on map projections with matplotlib
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org/basemap
Author: Jeff Whitaker
Author-email: jeffrey.s.whitaker@noaa.gov
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\oName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages
Requires: basemap-data, matplotlib, numpy, pyproj, pyshp
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to delete all basemap files in my sitepackage folder after the command `pip uninstall basemap` and then perform `pip install basemap` again! now it works